# how to keep on scrolling the image when click and held the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image which is 3000px width which is put inside a 150px width. Also I have a left and right button, to scroll the image left and right within the div

```
<div id='box'><img src='img.png'/></div><a id='btnleft'>left</a><a id='btnright'>right</a>
```

I want to scroll the image to left. If `onclick` only then scroll 10px.  If `mousedown` then keep on scroll until the end of the image.  If `mouseup` stop scrolling.

```
var imgWidth = 3000;
var divWidth = 130;
var scrollwidth = imgWidth/divWidth;
$('#btnleft').click(function (){ $('#bg_img').animate({left: +=scrollwidth}); });
$('#btnright').click(function (){ $('#bg_img').animate({left: -=scrollwidth}); });
```

Should I count the mousedown time? How can I do that?

Comment: What you have tried in coding?

Comment: I tried using someting like pagination. But when I scrolled to the last page the postion is not correct.

Comment: @SFY Show us your current code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that will do just that :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmRPar?editors=001)

```
$(function() {

var box = $('#box'), overflow;

$(window).on('load resize', function() {

  var range = $('img').outerWidth();
  overflow = range-box.width();
});

$('button').on('mousedown', function() {

  var spot = box.scrollLeft();

  if (this.id == 'left-button') {
    var aim = 0,
    duration = spot;
  }
  else {
    aim = overflow;
    duration = aim-spot;
  }

  box.animate({scrollLeft: aim}, duration*5);
})
.on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {

  box.stop();
});
});
```

It doesn't meet the `10px` requirement exactly but there's simple no way to distinguish if or when the mousedown will become a click. So it's continuous instead but close to the expected result.

Nothing too mysterious, it checks the left scroll position on `mousedown` on the button then animates to either side. Duration is set according to the amount that will need to be scrolled to that position to keep a steady speed. Animation is stopped when the button fires a `mouseup` or `mouseleave`.

One line in the live example can be ignored (it's for a Codepen glitch, has a comment above it).

Comment: I have a question, What does $('#box'), overflow mean?

Comment: Glad I could help out, thanks for following up. I am declaring two variables there. Putting a comma in between is just a little bit shorter than `var box = $('#box'); var overflow;`. Hope that explains it.

Comment: I am too stupid, is it possible to put in document $(document).ready(function()  ?

Comment: It's already wrapped in a `$(function() { ... });` which is shorthand for that. Should work as an external (linked) script - or in the document itself but then it needs `<script>` tags around it of course.